# query Redirect issue with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to setup a query redirect for my category pages

Currently the url is as follows:

```
  http://chunkydeals.com/daily-deals/?category=alldeals
```

I am trying to get it to be something like:

```
  http://chunkydeals.com/daily-deals/alldeals/
```

my htaccess code is as follows:

```
  # BEGIN WordPress

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([a-z])*)$
  RewriteRule ^daily-deals/$ http://chunkydeals.com/daily-deals/%3/? [R=301,L]

  </IfModule>

  # END WordPress
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: And what is you issue exactly? (I broke my crystal ball yesterday. Strange I could predict that that was going to happen.)

Comment: it is not rewriting the way it's supposed to. i have tried multiple combinations to do the rewrite. i either get a 404 error or the page with no images.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the QUERY_STRING rules above the one that rewrites to index.php? (which prevents the regex `^daily-deals/$` from matching)

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([a-z])*)$
RewriteRule ^daily-deals/$ http://chunkydeals.com/daily-deals/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```